# how to open a popup including external site (addon SDK)?

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying just to open a new popup HTML page (from )

```
window.open ('http://www.google.fr', 'win', 'height=240, width=640, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no');
```

Looks like windows does not have options to specify width, height and other options.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use `Low-Level` SDK API called `'window/utils'` and its `openDialog()` function (instead of `open()`), which provides more `features` to set.

```
require('sdk/window/utils').openDialog({
  url: 'http://www.google.fr',
  name: 'The window I dreamt of',
  features: 'height = 240,' +
            'width = 640,' +
            'toolbar = no,' +
            'menubar = no,' +
            'scrollbars = no,' +
            'resizable = no,' +
            'location = no,' +
            'directories = no,' +
            'status = no'
});
```

This API is described here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/window_utils

And here you can find full list of supported `features` for `openDialog()`:
https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Comment: I think it should. Do you perhaps get console error "TypeError: getBrowserForTab(...) is null" when testing your add-on?

Comment: No: I just don't know how to attach a worker to it (or any other method)